# how to show/start animation in each page of viewPager in android?

Tags: android, animation, android-viewpager, slideshow

I want to show some images as very simple animation in `viewPager`(each page of `ViewPager` has different animation). 
My `ViewPager` code:

```
public class Sport2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sport1);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);


   // tab layout for circle of view pager
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabDots);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

}

//********Adapter class*********************************************************
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new EyeSportFragment();
                //return FragmentWithOneImage.newInstance("Fragment 1", R.drawable.android_1);
            case 1:
                return new FingerSportFragment();
            case 2:
                return new NeckSportFinger();
            case 3:
                return new WristSportFragment();
            case 4:
                return new ShoulderSportFragment();
            case 5:
                return new BackSportFragment();
            case 6:
                return new WaterFragment();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() { // Show 3 total pages.
        return 7;
    }
```

and animation class:

```
    public class BackSportFragment extends Fragment {
    private ImageView sportShowing_img;

    public BackSportFragment() {
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sport_show, container, false);
        sportShowing_img= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.sport_img);



        AnimationDrawable animation = new AnimationDrawable();
        animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_hardware_keyboard_arrow_left), 1000); //1 Sec
        animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_action_home), 1000); //1 Sec
        animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cast_ic_notification_1), 1000); //1 Sec
        animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_light), 1000); //1 Sec
        animation.setOneShot(true);

        sportShowing_img.setBackgroundDrawable(animation);
        animation.start();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                sportShowing_img.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }, 10000);
        return view;
    }

}
```

how can I do `ViewPager` that with clicking/scrolling on each page, its animation starts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement `OnPageChangeListener` [*Callback interface for responding to changing state of the selected page*] interface on your `Activity`

Define the `onPageSelected()` method like below:

```
@Override
public abstract void onPageSelected (int position){
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"In the page " + position, 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
// depends on the position display your relevant animation
}
```

And don't forget to call

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
```

Comment: i create ` public static boolean anim_started=false;` in Fragment class. where should i put `if` method and check its value?

Comment: didnt get your real problem. you have each animation in each fragment right.? if yes anims will load inside fragments then you won't have a prblem .. is that what you do or something else.. if you want to usee bool and avoild load the next one till anim ends but its not user friendly

Comment: i find my answer! `animation.setOneShot(true);` must delete.

Comment: glad you made it :) ,even though i am wondering how its possible to get all that anim methods called at a time.if you use that cal from onpageChageListner to call each one only with the related position